# how can I add unique key prop in each child in a list on react?

Tags: reactjs, key, uniqueidentifier, unique-key

[I keep getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nt270.png)

I am trying to solve this warning.

Answer (score 0):

If movies don't have an id and you just want to get rid of the warning, you can use the second argument of the map function, which returns the index:

```
movieDB[movie].map((movies, index) => {
  <li className='items' key={index}>
    ...
  </li>
})
```

Comment: adding index as key is not a solution, as react automatically adds index as key if key is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I think that every movie name is unique, so you can just

```
<li classname='items' key={movies.name}>
```

Comment: Not working , I'm still getting warning

Comment: you are getting warning because its a different one, screenshot shows line 100+ and error is coming from line 80, I guess you have another .map function without key, so you do the same and it will be gone